# Find selector in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, selector

I have to find and display a selector from HTML presented in array, this works for me using Jquery:

```
var a = '';
var b = Array.prototype.map.call($('p', a),
 function(e) { return e.outerHTML; });

console.log(b)
```

However I don't want to use Jquery, Id rather use plain Javascript so I tried:

```
a.querySelectorAll('p')
```

Not working. Why is that and what else can I try?

Comment: What's `a`.  Is it a DOM element or a string?  Also, *what*'s not working?  What error do you see?

Comment: Works just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/knh2n8wy/**

Comment: I was doing something wrong...hard to explain: listening to event DOM mutations and try to alter them but now I realize I was just calling from the DOM...anyway Im going to accept an answer as it fits the question. a= array from mutation record and console says 'undefined is not a function'

Comment: You might be getting the 'undefined is not a function' error because the `querySelectorAll` function is being looked up in the `Array.prototype`. Because `querySelectorAll` is not found, `a.querySelectorAll` will return undefined. Finally, trying to invoke an undefined value will cause that error.  
Try this (for example):
`var und = undefined;`
`und();`

Comment: @Joseph Ahn I know, but I thought I was doing something else. But when I saw that document.queryselector worked I realized I was just calling things from the document instead from within the scope of my mutation function (arrays/strings and what else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `querySelectorAll` as if it is available in the `String.prototype` object because the variable `a` is an empty string.

Try `document.querySelectorAll('p');`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
var b = Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("p"),
  function(e) { return e.outerHTML; });

console.log(b);
```

This way your calling the query selector on the document rater than on an empty string(where the function won't exist).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")
```

Which will return an array of all `<p>` tags